# Reuse ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project from GitHub

Tags: c#, github, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a really bare bones ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project in GitHub.  It's just a simple project with JWT auth functionality. It's got a simple service, a couple of models and an auth controller.

I don't want to continually rewrite this code every time I create a new Web API project. Is there a simple way to make it into a template somehow where I can just pull the code into a new project?

I've been cloning the repo and going through the process of renaming the project, which is a huge pain to have to do every time. There's got to be a better way to do this right? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can create a project template. In Visual Studio, There is an option on the Project menu -> Export Template.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-project-template

Comment: You can have a try the shared link and tutorial, if you still have any concern feel free to share us.

Comment: you can have a look at the article which explains in details about the process of creating project template. https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/create-asp-net-core-web-api-project-template-9fd4b1e17fc8

Comment: Thanks guys, yes Project Templates are exactly what I was looking for.  Much appreciated!